# How to return @RepositoryRestResource style responses from a @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

Using the @RepositoryRestResource generates paths and injects all the necessary HATEOAS links for a REST API, but when I return the same results from the repository using a controller the JSON structure is different and there are no HATEOAS links.

How would I return get the same JSON structure from a controller as the RepositoryRestResource generated paths?

```
// /accounts (RepositoryRestResource JSON structure)
{
    _embedded: {
        accounts: []
    },
    _links: {
        first: {},
        self: {},
        next: {},
        last: {},
        profile: {},
        search: {}
    },
    page: {
    size: 20,
    totalElements: 35,
    totalPages: 2,
    number: 0
    }
}

// /my-accounts (RestController JSON structure)
{
    content: [ ... ], // accounts
    pageable: {},
    totalPages: 1,
    totalElements: 2,
    last: true,
    size: 20,
    number: 0,
    sort: {},
    numberOfElements: 2,
    first: true
}
```

REST Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "accounts", path = "accounts", itemResourceRel = "account")
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "owner", rel = "owner")
    Page<Account> findByOwner(@Param("username") String owner,Pageable p);
}
```

REST Controller:

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    private AccountRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(AccountRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(
        path = "/my-accounts",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/hal+json")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Account>> getStatus(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "20", required = false) int size,
        Authentication authentication) {

        String username =  authentication.getName();

        Page<Account> accounts = repo.findByOwner(username, PageRequest.of(page, size));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(accounts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Spring Data REST is just a default implementation of a boilerplate code (like controllers) which people usually write exposing Spring Data repositories via REST and using Spring HATEOAS, i.e. trying to reproduce exactly the same effect with your hand-written controller means just writing the whole Spring Data REST on your own, so, it is a bad idea. Luckily, *some parts* are easy to reproduce though.

If you speak only about adding paging links to your controller's output (and **not** implementing other things like search controller, to which a link is present in your sample Spring Data REST controller output), you may take a look at [how Spring Data REST does it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/AbstractRepositoryRestController.java#L94). It uses Spring Data's [PagedResourcesAssembler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PagedResourcesAssembler.java), which accepts a `Page` and creates a HATEOAS resource with the required navigation links.

So, to add the paging links, you must inject a `PagedResourcesAssembler` instance in your controller and use it:

```
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources> getStatus(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int page,
    @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "20", required = false) int size,
    Authentication authentication,
    PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {

    String username =  authentication.getName();

    Page<Account> accounts = repo.findByOwner(username, PageRequest.of(page, size));

    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toResource(accounts));
}
```

Comment: That works! I knew there had to be a way to get to that assembler used by RepositoryRestResource. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this might do the trick:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(new org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<>(accounts));
```

If not then you could wrap the accounts in a class that extends ResourceSupport. So just create some class `AccountSupport extends ResourceSupport` and add the required links in there. It has a lot of utility methods like

```
add(linkTo(AccountController.class).withSelfRel());
```

or for links to individual Accounts:

```
add(linkTo(AccountController.class).slash(idOfYourAccountInstance).withSelfRel())
```

Comment: No, that doesn't seem make a difference , it is the same JSON the controller was producing before.

Comment: Sorry I had that code as an alternative in some old repository but I just checked it out and you're right. In that repo the actual solution used was what I edited into the answer now.